# Mocking IStringLocalizer with nsubstitute

Tags: .net, unit-testing, mocking, nsubstitute

I'm trying to get nsubstitute to mock an instance of `IStringLocalizer` like this

```
var mock = Substitute.For<IStringLocalizer<SomeClass>>();
mock["Foo"].Returns("Bar");
Assert.That(mock["Foo"], Is.EqualTo("Bar"));
```

How can I do this?

Comment: What's not working? Any error messages? What is IStringLocalizer?

Answer (score 6):

If you want a generic mock that simply returns the ressoure code as translation result, you can use this :

```cs
mock[Arg.Any<string>()].Returns(p => new LocalizedString((string)p[0], (string)p[0]));
```

Answer (score 4):

Try this:

```
var mock = Substitute.For<IStringLocalizer<SomeClass>>();

mock["Foo"].Returns(new LocalizedString("Foo", "XXXXXXXA"));
Console.WriteLine(mock["Foo"]); // -> Write "XXXXXXXA"
```

In documentation of `IStringLocalizer` you can see that indexer of this type are returns `LocalizedString` which can not be explicit/implicit cast to `System.String` so you need to specify explicitly new `LocalizedString` for `Returns` method.